# Jquery Click event of <a> tag added at run time doesn't get fired

Tags: jquery

I am adding  tag at run time using jquery.

```
<a id=add class=add href=#>Test</a>
```

I want to fire the click event of this  tag but it doesn't get fired.

I have already tried

```
$('#add').bind('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
  alert('hello');

});
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to bind it using **.live()**

```
$('#add').live('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('hello');
});
```

The .live() method is able to affect elements that have not yet been added to the DOM through the use of event delegation.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: .live() method Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future.

Comment: Yup Dee is right, and to add to that .bind() only works for DOM w/c are added before the page has loaded. If you right click view source your page all the elements there can be selected by .bind() only. newly added DOM or on the fly created elements can be selected by .live()

Comment: isn't the .live method deprecated? From jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use a valid XHTML:

```
<a id="add" class="add" href="#">Test</a>
```

And in the jQuery:

```
$('#add').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: Who says he's using XHTML? What he's got is valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

after jquery 1.7

```
$( 'document').on( "click",'#step',  function() {
               console.log("Clicking step"); 
});
```

Comment: btw the quotes around document are not needed. Nonetheless - good job for mentioning .on() instead of the deprecated .live() method.